# Proper way to initialize dependent package in R, example using ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap, r-package

I'm developing a package that uses ggmap as a dependency.

ggmap: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap

Within my package, I'm calling ggmap function using the recommended approach of including ggmap in the `Imports` section of the `Description` file, and calling functions using the `::` operator (e.g. `ggmap::get_map()`). My issue is that ggmap assumes that some options are set upon initialization in `.onLoad()`.

https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/R/attach.R

I believe that, since I'm not calling `library()` or `require()`, `.onAttach()` never gets called, and thus these options never get set. I can't call `.onAttach()` within my package, because it is not exported.

What is the best practice for initializing a dependent package?

This seems like a general problem in R package development, but I can't find the answer anywhere. And my apologies, this doesn't seem like the kind of question that can have a reproducible example.

Comment: Take a look at the book [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html). I generally use [`usethis`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/) to make sure I'm doing things like importing functions correctly. You shouldn't be calling `library` or `require` within any of your package's code

Comment: Hi Camille, thanks for your comment! I have already read over R Packages book, but I took another look. I don't see any clear answers there. Maybe it's an issue with ggmap--the package initilizes using .onAttach(), but recommended practice is that I should not attach the package. I also can't see how usethis can help. The closest thing I can see is the use_package() function, but this does not help with calling .onAttach as far as I can see. If you had something specific in mind with your comment above, would you mind providing more detail? Thank you!

Comment: Ahh I see, I didn't totally understand what was in `.onAttach`. Looking at the `ggmap` source, that calls a function `bootstrap_ggmap` which in turn calls `set_ggmap_option`, which is exported. Could you call `set_ggmap_option` within your own package's setup code? That's probably not as smooth as you would like though, but it seems like that's the main thing done in `.onAttach`.

Comment: Thank you! Calling `set_ggmap_option` is what I ended up doing. It seems like a bit of a hack though, and since I'm using the development version of the code, I've had to hunt through code and manually initialize the package a couple times whenever the code changes. I was hoping there was a general, cleaner, best practice method to use this package without having to hack the initialization every time. Maybe not though! I've contacted the package owner as well; perhaps the package needs to use `.onLoad` instead of `.onAttach`. I really don't know.